# How can I reuse a path with transformations inside animateMotion?

Tags: animation, svg, transformation, motion

In the code below I have a spiral path, a copy of the path rotated 180 degrees, and a circle that moves along the original path.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g transform="translate(50 50) scale(3)">
    <path id="spiral1" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="M 3.108,0 C 3.178,0.407 3.171,0.842 3.074,1.273 S 2.791,2.132 2.519,2.519 S 1.887,3.253 1.46,3.524 S 0.534,3.991 0,4.084 S -1.107,4.167 -1.673,4.04 S -2.802,3.668 -3.311,3.311 S -4.275,2.48 -4.631,1.918 S -5.245,0.702 -5.367,0 S -5.476,-1.455 -5.309,-2.199 S -4.821,-3.683 -4.351,-4.351 S -3.26,-5.618 -2.521,-6.087 S -0.922,-6.893 0,-7.054 S 1.912,-7.197 2.89,-6.978 S 4.84,-6.336 5.718,-5.718 S 7.384,-4.284 7.999,-3.313 S 9.059,-1.212 9.27,0 S 9.458,2.513 9.17,3.798 S 8.327,6.361 7.515,7.515 S 5.63,9.704 4.355,10.513 S 1.593,11.906 0,12.183 S -3.302,12.43 -4.992,12.052 S -8.36,10.943 -9.876,9.876 S -12.753,7.399 -13.816,5.723 S -15.647,2.094 -16.012,0"/>
    <use id="spiral2" xlink:href="#spiral1" transform="rotate(180)" />
    <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="red">
      <animateMotion dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#spiral1" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want to have a second circle moving along the rotated path. But when I change `<mpath xlink:href="#spiral1" />` to use `#spiral2` the circle no longer moves. I also tried sticking to `spiral1` but adding `transform="rotate(180)"` to the `mpath`. It didn't help.

Ultimately I don't need to draw the paths, I only want to move along them, but I want to use transformations instead of duplicating the path definition.

Comment: As it's name suggests [mpath's href must point to a path](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#MPathElement). If you want to reuse paths, you can use javascript to clone them.

Comment: @RobertLongson this question is obsolete now but out of curiosity, do you have any idea why a `<use>` doesn't simply behave like the tag that it points to?

Comment: Because the SVG specification says so, as you can see if you read the link.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way: draw the second spiral and circle inside a `g` which transforms everything.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g transform="translate(50 50) scale(3)">
    <path id="spiral1" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="M 3.108,0 C 3.178,0.407 3.171,0.842 3.074,1.273 S 2.791,2.132 2.519,2.519 S 1.887,3.253 1.46,3.524 S 0.534,3.991 0,4.084 S -1.107,4.167 -1.673,4.04 S -2.802,3.668 -3.311,3.311 S -4.275,2.48 -4.631,1.918 S -5.245,0.702 -5.367,0 S -5.476,-1.455 -5.309,-2.199 S -4.821,-3.683 -4.351,-4.351 S -3.26,-5.618 -2.521,-6.087 S -0.922,-6.893 0,-7.054 S 1.912,-7.197 2.89,-6.978 S 4.84,-6.336 5.718,-5.718 S 7.384,-4.284 7.999,-3.313 S 9.059,-1.212 9.27,0 S 9.458,2.513 9.17,3.798 S 8.327,6.361 7.515,7.515 S 5.63,9.704 4.355,10.513 S 1.593,11.906 0,12.183 S -3.302,12.43 -4.992,12.052 S -8.36,10.943 -9.876,9.876 S -12.753,7.399 -13.816,5.723 S -15.647,2.094 -16.012,0"
    />
    <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="red">
      <animateMotion dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite">
        <mpath xlink:href="#spiral1" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <g transform="rotate(180)">
      <use id="spiral2" xlink:href="#spiral1" />
      <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="red">
        <animateMotion dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite">
          <mpath xlink:href="#spiral1" />
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```